Why is Firefox still showing page tabs in kiosk mode on macOS?
I have Firefox 125 on macOS and want to use kiosk mode for its intended purpose i.e. allow users to access a specific web site but not navigate away from it, hide as much of the UI as possible, etc.
In the official Firefox Enterprise Kiosk mode documentation it says

Key characteristics of the Firefox Enterprise Kiosk mode:

Runs in full screen mode by default
All menus, awesome bar and toolbar are not visible as well as tabs
etc...


so why is it that when I start Firefox in kiosk mode the tabs are still displayed:

I get the same result when I run kiosk mode with the -private-window flag. Do I need to include some other flags in the command to get the desired result?
Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!
